# How to avoid windows default scrollbar horizontally when header and and footer is fixed in jQuery and use stickytableheaders in that?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a screen which displays data in a table column.In that screen both header and footer are fixed. So , now I am using [stickytableheaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) to fix the table header. When I am using it, the window scrollbar is coming under footer as the table contains numbers of columns.

But what I am trying is to have a scroll bar above the footer and perform stickytableheaders.

Can anyone solve my issue.

Comment: use css not jquery. `overflow: hidden;` is your friend.

Comment: When i use overflow:hidden , the table is not getting overflow,as many columns are exceeding the window screen.I am unable to see the other columns which exceed the window screen

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
html{overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;}